# How to sort HashMap<String, String[]> by String in android

Tags: android, string, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have this code:

```
    HashMap<String, String[]> unsorted = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    String[] values = new String[3];
    String key;

    //add data to hashmap
    key = "abc";
    values[0] = "a"; values[1]="b"; values[2]="c";
    unsorted.put(key, values);

    key = "abc";
    values[0] = "aa"; values[1]="bb"; values[2]="cb";
    unsorted.put(key, values);

    key = "def";
    values[0] = "d"; values[1]="e"; values[2]="f";
    unsorted.put(key, values);

    //sort hashmap
    /***********/

    //output should be:
    { abc-[a,b,c], abc-[aa,bb,cc], def-[d,e,f] }

    //or

    { abc-[aa,bb,cc], abc-[a,b,c], def-[d,e,f] }
```

How can I sort it like that? Note: I tried with using TreeMap, and other examples, but they eliminate the elements where the *keys* are equal.

**Edit:** I solved my problem :) thanks to Guillaume. Here is what I used:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<CustomObject> objs = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();

    objs.add(new CustomObject("abc", new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}));
    objs.add(new CustomObject("def", new String[] {"d", "e", "f"}));
    objs.add(new CustomObject("abc", new String[] {"aa", "bb", "cc"}));


    System.out.println(objs.isEmpty());

    Collections.sort(objs, new Comparator<CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CustomObject o1, CustomObject o2) {
            int i = o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
            if(i == 0)
                return -1;
            return i;
        }
    });

    for(int i=0; i<objs.size(); i++)
        System.out.println("key/value pair:" + objs.get(i).getKey() + " - " + objs.get(i).getValues()[0]);
    }
}
```

And the CustomObject:

```
public class CustomObject {

private String key;
private String[] values;

public CustomObject(String key, String[] values) {
    this.key = key;
    this.values = values;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public String[] getValues() {
    return values;
}
}
```

Comment: A map is **supposed** to have only one element for each key. Why don't you put in string arrays in your TreeMap, as you do with the HashMap?

Comment: Note that, if you ever need to have your elements in a map in natural order based on a comparator, use the implementation TreeMap, not the HashMap. No Map implementation in the JDK allows duplicate keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need special ordering, and the ability to have multiple objects that have an equal "key", that screams for `List`, with a custom `Comparator`.

1- Define a class of elements to store in your list. In your case, it's an object that has 2 fields: a "key" and an array of String. Let's call it `CustomObject` (you can call it as you like)

2- Stick all your objects in the list

Like that:

```
list.add(new CustomObject("abc", new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
list.add(new CustomObject("abc", new String[] {"aa", "bb", "cc"});
list.add(new CustomObject("def", new String[] {"d", "e", "f"});
```

3- Order your list using a custom comparator.

To order the list do

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CustomObject o1, CustomObject o2) {
            return o1.getArray().compare(o2.getArray());
        }
    });
```

(your comparator needs to be a bit more sophisticated, to properly compare arrays, but you see my point).

---

An alternative to that is to add a natural ordering to your `CustomObject` (implements `Comparable`), and stick them into a `TreeSet`.

Comment: thanks, I'll try the first method, but do I have to define every function for the items list?? (public void add(int index, CustomObject element), public CustomObject get(int index), etc)

Comment: No, no, use an ArrayList :) I said List because it's the interface, use any of its implementations (ArrayList or LinkedList)

Comment: Glad it helped :) But really, you should find a proper name instead of CustomObject, something that describes what your objects are

Answer (score 3):

The HashMap can not be sorted (or contain duplicate keys), it is part of how it is implemented [(see the documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

So you better do as other people are suggesting and switch to a list or a different map implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort your hashmap using following method

```
private static HashMap sortByValues(HashMap map) {
        List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
        // Defined Custom Comparator here
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                        .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
            }
        });

        // Here I am copying the sorted list in HashMap
        // using LinkedHashMap to preserve the insertion order
        HashMap sortedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            sortedHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return sortedHashMap;
    }
```

call method like
//shift your hashmap

```
 shift =sortByValues(shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Map that allows duplicate keys, there is no such Map in the JDK. Try using a Multimap in Google guava. 
http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

An implementation that have natural order is the TreeMultiMap: 
http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html

Good luck :)